# Return Value Not Currently Assigned from MYSQL Database

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a piece of mysqly which currently, returns all the team id's being currently in use. However, in this instance I would like it to return all the teams id's which haven't been assigned.

How could this be achieved?

```
SELECT

*                                          

FROM 
 leagueInformation li                                            

 INNER JOIN 
    teams t ON t.teamID = li.teamID

 WHERE li.leagueID = 1 AND li.seasonID = 1 

GROUP BY 
  t.teamName

ORDER BY 
  t.teamID
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM teams 
WHERE TeamID NOT IN (
    SELECT TeamID 
    FROM leagueInformation 
    WHERE leagueID = 1 AND seasonID = 1
)
```

Comment: Just for future reference to anyone using this in the where clause you need to assign a column name to id in may case it was teamID. Hope this helps !

Comment: tend to use EXISTS instead of IN for subqueries.

Comment: @user3393730 I understood what you mean and updated code. Sorry, for that, my bad.

Answer (score 0):

Left / right join option:

```
SELECT t.*                                          
FROM 
 leagueInformation li RIGHT JOIN 
 teams t ON t.teamID = li.teamID
WHERE li.teamID IS NULL
```

Or EXISTS:

```
SELECT t.*                                          
FROM 
 teams t
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM leagueInformation WHERE teamID = t.teamID)
```